# Error : self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to enter to each link and print the text that appears in the page but I have this errors:

```
    in <module>driver.get(url)
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
    in executeself.error_handler.check_response(response)
    in check_response raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: 
    invalid argument
```

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import os
import time

path = "example"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get("https://www.abdsd.com")
main_div = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "site-container"))
        )
links = main_div.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "a")
for link in links:
    url = link.get_attribute('href')
    driver.get(url)
    for txt in driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH,value="/html/body"):
        print(txt)
```

Comment: Update the question with the complete error stacktrace.

Comment: @nbvnbv can you update the error please

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to the chrome version 103, which I had this error when trying driver.get() and it didn't do anything, the error just pops up. To fix it you can download and use chrome beta 104, and also use chrome web driver 104.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).